# Getting grep in Perl to filter directory listings

Tags: arrays, perl, filter, grep

I'm having trouble getting the Perl `grep` command to filter a directory listing. I've spent a while searching around and trying new things but can't get it to run.

Here is the code:

```
$findcikstr = "!/" . $cik . "-10-K-" . $cikyear . "........./"; #(!/1534155-10-K-2013........../)
 @array = grep($findcikstr, <*>);
```

I can't get it to filter any of the results.

The pattern I am looking for, is for a specific CIK (7-digit number), and year to find all files of the form

```
#######-10-K-YYYY*.txt
```

where the CIK is #######, and the year is YYYY. A full filename would be

```
1534155-10-K-2013-10-29.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is a truthy string, which always evaluates to true, which means you get back all the list elements you passed in.

```
my @filtered = grep { /^$cik-10-K-$cikyear/ } <*>;
```